# How to add a trendline (exponential) in R?

Tags: programming-languages, graph, r

Okay, so I am working with the daily closings of the Dow Jones Industrial Average (DJIA) index from January 1979 to December 1989. I have successfully plotted the time-evolution of the index, but I am stumped as to how to add a trendline (specifically, exponential). You can get the data here:

http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/DJIA/downloaddata

I just downloaded it to Excel and then imported it to R as a csv file and plotted it.

In addition to that, how can I add a trendline at a specific place? Say, I wanted a trendline from the year 1985 to 1988?

Comment: You're going to need to add a bit more detail here - how you have plotted it for example!

Comment: Are you asking how to plot a trendline, or how to calculate the parameters of a fit of your data to an exponential curve?

Comment: Basically just an exponential regression... through the glorious power of Excel, I know that the equation of the line is y=0.0629e^0.0003x, with R^2=0.90456

Comment: I have to say that, unless your "x' values are extremely large, I wouldn't consider an exponent of that magnitude justification for claiming the underlying data are exponential.  What happens when you fit a line or a parabola?

Answer (score 1):

If that's literally what you want to do (I suspect it isn't), then all you have to do is plot and add a `curve` with the specified function of x:

```
plot(y~x)
par(new=TRUE)
curve(0.0629*exp(0.0003*x))
```

If you actually want to fit a curve based on something you do in R, you'll have to generate some kind of model and then plot fitted values from that using basically the same thing but instead of `curve` you could use `lines`.